# Images are not showing after nuxt generate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, deployment, nuxt.js, single-page-application

After nuxt generate as target: 'static', images are not showing when we run the dist build by npm run start.
though in dev mode images are showing correctly.
I have used image URLs as src of img.
when we inspect on the browser, its showing links are there but not rendering on the page.

Versions
nuxt: "^2.15.7"
node: v14.17.4

What is Expected?
Images should work after generate.

Comment: What do you mean by `not rendering on the page`? Also, do you have a [repro] or a link?

Comment: @kissu I mean images are not showing on the page, only alt msgs are showing same happening with videos.

Comment: Where are stored your images (which folder)? What value has your <img src="???"> ? Did you follow https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/static/ ?